# MVC 6 complex model binding

Tags: viewmodel, model-binding, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement a complex view model and bind it to a form. Unfortunately the binding seems to drop/miss the child model prefix so when I try to submit the model back the model binder does not know how to interpret the data. Here's a simplified version of the code...

**Parent model**

```
public class MainVM
{
    public bool MainProperty1 { get; set; }

    public ChildVM ChildModel { get; set; }
}
```

**Child model**

```
public class ChildVM
{
    public int ChildProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string ChildProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string ChildProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@model MainVM

<form id="main-form" asp-controller="main" asp-action="submit" method="post"> 
   <div>
      @await Html.PartialAsync("partial", Model.ChildModel)
   </div>
</form>
```

**partial.cshtml**

```
@model ChildVM

<div>
   <input asp-for="ChildProperty1" />
   <input asp-for="ChildProperty2" />
   <input asp-for="ChildProperty3" />
</div>
```

**Output**

```
<form id="main-form" method="post" action="/main/submit">    
   <div>
      <div>
         <input type="text" data-val="true" name="ChildProperty1" data-val-maxlength-max="17" data-val-minlength-min="4" id="ChildProperty1" />
         <input type="text" data-val="true" name="ChildProperty2" data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-minlength-min="3" id="ChildProperty2" />
         <input type="text" data-val="true" name="ChildProperty3" data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-minlength-min="3" id="ChildProperty3" />
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

As you can see the binding on the name attribute is missing the prefix of `ChildVM` (ex. `name="ChildVM.ChildProperty1"`) My question is why would this be dropped or missing?  Not sure what I'm missing or if this is a MVC6 thing because as far as I'm aware, this should just work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. If you want to keep the view model structure as it is and still want model binding to work you can try either of the following solutions.

**Explicitly specifying the name property value of the inputs**

In the main view, you can explicitly specify that your input form is for the child property of the model using the `asp-for` tag

```
@model MainVM
<form id="main-form" asp-controller="main" asp-action="submit" method="post">

    <input asp-for="MainProperty1" />
    <div>
        <h5>Child items</h5>
        <input asp-for="ChildModel.ChildProperty1"/>
        <input asp-for="ChildModel.ChildProperty2"/>
        <input asp-for="ChildModel.ChildProperty3"/>

    </div>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This will generate input fields with name property such as `name="ChildModel.ChildProperty1"` and `name="ChildModel.ChildProperty2"` etc.. And model binding will work fine when you post the form.

**Use an editor template**

You can create a new directory called `EditorTemplates` under `~/Views/YourCurrentControllerName` and create a new view called `ChildVM.cshtml` under that and paste the following code to that

```
@model ChildVM
<div>
    <input asp-for="ChildProperty1"/>
    <input asp-for="ChildProperty2"/>
    <input asp-for="ChildProperty3"/>
</div>
```

And in the main view, use `Html.EditorFor` helper method

```
@model MainVM
<form id="main-form" asp-controller="main" asp-action="submit" method="post">

    <input asp-for="MainProperty1" />
    @Html.EditorFor(s => s.ChildModel)
    <input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

This will also generate input fields with name property such as `name="ChildModel.ChildProperty1"` and `name="ChildModel.ChildProperty2"` etc.. And model binding will work fine when you post the form.

Comment: Thank you Shyju, appreciate the details you listed here. Spent most of the afternoon reading up on data-binding and settled on editor templates.

Comment: @AnthonySherratt You are welcome ! Glad i could help :)

Comment: Terrific explanation @Shyju you saved me a heap of work with your examples.

Comment: Very informative @Shyju. However, I have a case where I need to use `MainVM. MainProperty1` in the are that is supposed to be in the editor template (I need to use `MainVM.MainProperty1` in between `asp-for="ChildModel.ChildPropertyX"` instances). So for my case I think an editor template may not work. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

- `why would this be dropped or missing`

Neither it's dropped nor missing. Because child view will not be aware whether it's model is having any parent or not. It'll just know that `ChildVM` is it's model, and `name` it's properties without any prefix.

Comment: From  the examples I have seen, this is how they presented it. Maybe I'm not understanding how parent/child model binding works. Do you have an example of how I can bind my child model to a partial view and still hold the correct bindings?